# nth root function

Tags: functions, arithmetic, exponential-function, radicals

I want to write code for a nth root function, so I need to be sure, that the underlying mathematical function is correct. From another post over at SO, I wrote the following definition:

$
\sqrt[x]{y} = y^{\frac{1}{x}} = \left\{
{\begin{array}{rl}
\exp_{2}\left(x \cdot \log_2 \left(\frac{1}{y}\right)\right) & \text{if } y > 0\\
-\exp_{2}\left(x \cdot \log_2 \left(\frac{1}{\left\lvert{y}\right\rvert}\right)\right) & \text{if } (y < 0) \land \left((y \equiv 1 \mod 2) \lor \left(\frac{1}{y} \equiv 1 \mod 2\right)\right)\\
\exp_{2}\left(x \cdot \log_2 \left(\frac{1}{\left\lvert{y}\right\rvert}\right)\right) & \text{if } (y < 0) \land \left((y \equiv 0 \mod 2) \lor \left(\frac{1}{y} \equiv 0 \mod 2\right)\right)
\end{array}}
\right.
$

Is this function definition correct?

**EDIT#1**

Link to the other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34221713/how-to-calculate-python-float-number-th-root-of-float-number/34223324#34223324

**EDIT#2**

What I want to achieve is a function, that can calculate the nth-root of any positive rational number, where n can be rational as well.

**EDIT#3**

I've not checked the variable positions again and this is what I have now:

$
\sqrt[\frac{n}{m}]{a} = a^{\frac{m}{n}} = \left\{
{\begin{array}{rl}
\exp_{2}\left(\frac{m}{n} \cdot \log_2 \left(a\right)\right) & \text{if } a > 0\\
-\exp_{2}\left(\frac{m}{n} \cdot \log_2 \left(a\right)\right) & \text{if } (a < 0) \land \left((x \equiv 1 \mod 2) \lor \left(\frac{1}{x} \equiv 1 \mod 2\right)\right)\\
\exp_{2}\left(\frac{m}{n} \cdot \log_2 \left(a\right)\right) & \text{if } (a < 0) \land \left((x \equiv 0 \mod 2) \lor \left(\frac{1}{x} \equiv 0 \mod 2\right)\right)
\end{array}}
\right.
$

Comment: Is $y$ an integer?

Comment: Please edit the question to include a link to the other post you mentioned. It might help people better understand what you're doing.

Comment: What does $exp_2$ mean?

Comment: The formula looks a little bit like something someone _might_ write for a definition of an $n$th root function, but there seem to be several errors in it.

Comment: Assuming $exp_2 (x)$ is simply $2$ raised to the power $x$, I invite you to take a look at this link, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E%28%28log_2%281%2F3%29%29%284%29%29+%3D+3%5E%281%2F4%29 , which shows that your definition does not capture the underlying mathematical definition of the $n$th root function. Perhaps a good start may be to replace your $x$'s with $\frac{1}{x}$'s

Comment: @DavidK Added link to the other description.

Comment: @moorish I don't understand what the link tells me about my formula. It doesn't look anything like what I wrote and I can't conclude anything from the input on wolframalpha (I am not a mathematician, I should mention).

Comment: The most prominent error seems to be that you've swapped $x$ and $y$ between the LHS and the RHS.

Comment: @Zelphir the link is a direct application of your formula with $y=3$ and $x=4$

Comment: Another way to look at the case $y=3$ and $x=4$ is http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E%28%28log_2%281%2F3%29%29%284%29%29+-+3%5E%281%2F4%29 -- it shows not only that the answer is wrong, it is wrong by a relatively large amount. It is very useful to do something like this, just pick some non-trivial values to plug into a formula, subtract the function you are trying to compute or approximate, and let Wolfram Alpha tell you large or small an error you made in your formula.

Comment: @DavidK Another problem was, that I myself didn't know exactly how to interpret the $exp_2$ part and also still don't know how to make wolframalpha understand that I want to calculate the nth root. I tried things like `Sqrt[n](a)` but that seems to be incorrect syntax and I couldn't find any better.

Comment: The exponentiation operator in WA is `^`. For $\sqrt[n]a$ write `a^(1/n)`. For $\exp_2(x)$ write `2^(x)`. For $\log_2$ write `log_2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula should be $y^{1/x}=2^{\frac{1}{x}\lg y}.$ And you should probably restrict your domain to just positive $y$ values unless you want to start getting imaginary values (e.g. $(-1)^{1/2} = \pm i)$.

Edit: If you want $a<0$ and want to find the $n^{th}$ (real) root, then you should make sure that $n$ is odd (otherwise you will get only imaginary roots); in this case $a^{1/n} = -(-a)^{1/n}.$ For $a^{m/n}$, we just do $(a^{1/n})^m$.

Comment: Ok maybe a restriction of y being positive would be a good idea, will edit my question.

Comment: Don't I have to use $log_2$, since I exponentiate 2? I thought, the formula can only be correct, when I do $log_2$ in case of $exp_2$, $log_3$ in case of $exp_3$ and so on, because they "balance each other".

Comment: @Zelphir Yeah. $\lg$ is another way to write $\log_2$

Comment: So $2^{\lg x} = x$